# Sitecore SXA: Placeholder rendering variant

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-sxa

This question is pretty straightforward. I plan to create a Link List rendering variant with a placeholder so I can extend its features. The problem I encountered was that it doesn't appear to be working for me.

Did I miss something? Are there SXA components that doesn't support placeholder fields? What are the renderings that support placeholder fields?

Thanks guys!

EDIT:I have tried this kind of structure as my link list's rendering variant.

[Rendering variant setup for link list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upof9.png)

But as a result, the placeholder is not rendered.

[No placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Wcj.png)

The placeholder you see is not from the subpanel, it's underneath it.

Comment: What have you tried, what isn't working? There is not enough information here to tell you what you're missing.

Comment: Hi @Nick ! Sorry about that, I have updated the question with my current set up for the rendering variant.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a Placeholder Settings item for your placeholder.

Placeholder Setting items are created under */sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings.*

Example: */sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Composites/accordion-heading*

The important thing here is the **Placeholder Key** field. In you case it will be: "placeholder*".

**The general pattern is "NAME_OF_THE_RENDERING*"**.

Rules for NAME_OF_THE_RENDERING

- use lowercase letters
- strip the following characters: [-_ ]+